# Mobile Opt-Ins and Sales Cloud MC Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Scenario: Fresh Sales Cloud with all records/objects imported and coming into Marketing Cloud via MC Connect. I want to create a Salesforce Data journey that will opt in subscribers to our join keyword.

Problem: Missing the required Locale field in Sales Cloud records.

Solution: I've read many articles on this and have gained a better understanding when using MobileConnect in a couple different scenarios, but in ones such as this, what would be the best way to send SMS to subscribers when we are using Sales Cloud and need to import the new required data?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to consider.

1. Salesforce side automation / perhaps some AppExchange solution, that would automatically add the Locale to a phone number depending on either the Billing or Shipping country.
2. Marketing Cloud Automation Studio solution where you will utilize SQL to write Locale values depending on the SF record Billing or Shipping country. This way you'll have the proper locale in your target Data Extension in Marketing Cloud exclusively - which you can also use with Script Activity to perform the necessary update on Sales Cloud records.

Ideally you should take care of this on the Sales Cloud side, by first updating all the existing records with a locale field value and then making it a required field / or automatically filled field whenever a phone number is added on an Account / Lead.

This way you will be able to utilize Salesforce Data as Entry Event to send an SMS immediately after criteria is filled (record update / creation).